# Pandas dataframe select Columns based on other dataframe contains column value in it

Tags: python, pandas, mask, isin

I have two dataframes. Here is `dwpjp.head()`:

|  | jp_number |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 25146315052147720191 |
| 1 | 57225427599900052634 |
| 2 | 86076681691411639833 |
| 3 | 50491824499499656478 |
| 4 | 95588382889227620465 |

and `ct_data.head()`:

|  | imjp_number | imct_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23605308039805192764 | x1E5e3ukRyEFRT6SUAF6lg|d543d3d064da465b8576d87 |
| 1 | 57225427599900052634 | aa0d2dac654d4154bf7c09f73faeaf62|-vf6738ee3bed |
| 2 | 53733358271401869469 | 6FfHZRoiWs2VO02Pruk07A|__g3d877adf9d154637be26 |
| 3 | 50491824499499656478 | __gbe204670ca784a01b7207b42a7e5a5d3|54e2c39cd3 |
| 4 | 82143248133286027306 | __g1114a30c6ea548a2a83d5a51718ff0fd|773840905c |

I want two new dataframes `cct_data`, and `dct_data` from `ct_data`. The `ct_data` dataframe should be split on the condition if the `jp_number` is present in the `dwbjp` dataframe then put into `cct_data`, otherwise put into `dct_data`.

I tried this for common `jp_number` present in `dwpjp`:

```
cct_data = ct_data[ct_data.isin(dwpjp).any(1).values]
```

and for the other I negated the condition as follows:

```
dct_data = ct_data[~[ct_data.isin(dwpjp).any(1).values]]
```

but results are not getting as below.

`cct_data`

|  | imjp_number | imct_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 57225427599900052634 | aa0d2dac654d4154bf7c09f73faeaf62|-vf6738ee3bed |
| 1 | 50491824499499656478 | __gbe204670ca784a01b7207b42a7e5a5d3|54e2c39cd3 |

and `dct_data`:

|  | imjp_number | imct_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 23605308039805192764 | x1E5e3ukRyEFRT6SUAF6lg|d543d3d064da465b8576d87 |
| 1 | 53733358271401869469 | 6FfHZRoiWs2VO02Pruk07A|__g3d877adf9d154637be26 |
| 2 | 82143248133286027306 | __g1114a30c6ea548a2a83d5a51718ff0fd|773840905c |

Note: `jpnumber=imjp_number`.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your formula as below

```
cct_data = ct_data[ct_data.imjp_number.isin(dwpjp.jp_number)]
```

and

```
dct_data = ct_data[~ct_data.imjp_number.isin(dwpjp.jp_number)]
```

Comment: This method taking too much time as ct_data have 50 records  and dwpjp have 3.5 M records, any faster way to achieve it?

Comment: It can be calculated fast by `cct_data = pd.merge(dwpjp, ct_data, on='jp_number', how='inner')` with assuming that both data frame having **jp_number** as commonly title columns name

Comment: Ramanai I got TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' error